# How to setup Notifications using Gmail API | Nodejs | Gmail API | Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, gmail, gmail-api

I am making a website where people can integrate multiple emails into one website.
Users have to log in using one of their emails. Once user integrates an email, a watch is setup (using /watch-inbox endpoint) which is triggered when the given email receives a new email. And further makes a POST request to (/gmail-notifications) endpoint.
Which has this data in req body -> `{"emailAddress":"example@gmail.com","historyId":123456}`

But as I mentioned above a single user can integrate multiple emails so, I need to setup watch for each of those emails, but I am not able to send notifications for each of those emails as in the req body, the `emailAddress` only consists of that email which received a new mail.
Because I need to search my DB for the tokens and other stuff, I need to use email for that, As the user is created with some other email address it will create a problem for searching the DB.

And suppose, there's a separate user that is created using one of the email addresses that is being integrated and if I use the same email that got a new email in the previous case and try to search my DB, it will result in this new user.

Is there a way I can set custom data in the watch response that i can access from /gmail-notifications body?

Here's how my schema looks like in DB

```
[

    {
        userName: "user",

        email: "example@gmail.com",
        appIntegrations: [
            {
                appName: "GMAIL",
                integrationData: [
                    {

                        emailUsed: "example@gmail.com",
                        tokens: {},
                        historyId: 123456
                    },

                ]

            },
            {
                appName: "GMAIL",
                integrationData: [
                    {

                        emailUsed: "test@gmail.com",
                        tokens: {},
                        historyId: 123456
                    },

                ]

            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Here's my Nodejs code:

```
app.post('/watch-inbox/v2/', async (req, res) => {
    const { userEmail, accountEmail } = req.query;
    const channel = {
        id: 'local-notifications',
        type: 'web_hook',
        address: `https://random-number.ngrok-free.app/gmail-notifications`,
    };

    const currUser = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail });
    const gmailAppDB = currUser.appIntegrations.find((app) => app.appName === "GMAIL" && app.integrationData.emailUsed === accountEmail);
    const tokensInDB = await gmailAppDB.integrationData.tokens;

    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        // access_token: tokensInDB.access_token,
        refresh_token: tokensInDB.refresh_token,
    });

    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });


    const response = await gmail.users.watch({
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            labelIds: ['SENT'],
            topicName: 'topicName/topics/gmail-notifications',
            labelFilterAction: 'exclude',
            notificationSettings: {
                transport: {
                    ...channel,
                },
                watchNewThread: true,
            },
        },
    });

    console.log('Watch response:', response.data);

    res.json({ response });
});


app.post('/gmail-notifications', async (req, res) => {

    console.log('notification received');
    const notification = req.body
    const messageId = notification.message.messageId;
    const encodedData = notification.message.data
    const decodedData = Buffer.from(encodedData, 'base64').toString('utf-8');

    const emailData = JSON.parse(decodedData)

    const currUser = await User.findOne({ email: emailData.emailAddress });
    const gmailAppDB = currUser.appIntegrations.find((app) => app.appName === "GMAIL" && app.integrationData.emailUsed === emailData.emailAddress);
    const tokensInDB = gmailAppDB.integrationData.tokens;
    const deviceTokens = currUser.deviceTokens[0]

    console.log('tokens > ', tokensInDB)

    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        // access_token: tokensInDB.access_token,
        refresh_token: tokensInDB.refresh_token,
    });

    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });

    const response = await gmail.users.history.list({
        userId: 'me',
        startHistoryId: gmailAppDB.integrationData.historyId
    }).catch(err => console.log('gmailnotification error >>> ', err));


    const getLatestEmails = async (newMsgData) => {

        const { threadId } = newMsgData
        console.log(threadId)

        try {
            const threadRes = await gmail.users.threads.get({
                userId: 'me',
                id: threadId,
                labelIds: ['UNREAD', '-DRAFT'],
            })
            console.log('thread messages: ', threadRes)
            return threadRes.data

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('it was a draft thread or ERROR: ', e)
        }
    }
    const addedMsgList = []

    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.log('response >> ', response.data)
        const latestMsg = response.data.history[response.data.history.length - 1].messagesAdded

        if (latestMsg) {
            console.log('latest msg: ', latestMsg)
            await Promise.all(
                response.data.history.map(async (elem) => {
                    if (elem.messagesAdded !== undefined) {
                        const data = await getLatestEmails(elem.messagesAdded[0].message)
                        const { threadId } = elem.messagesAdded[0].message
                        console.log('threadID to send: ', typeof threadId)
                        data !== undefined && addedMsgList.push(data)

                        if (data !== undefined) {
                            const subject = data.messages[0].payload.headers.find(header => header.name === 'Subject')?.value
                            console.log('subject to send: ', subject)

                            const message = {
                                "token": deviceTokens,
                                notification: {
                                    title: 'test from local',
                                    body: data.messages[0].snippet
                                },
                                "data": {
                                    "threadId": threadId
                                }
                            }

                            admin.messaging().send(message).then(res => {
                                console.log('sent: ', res)
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log('error sending notification: ', err)
                            })
                        } else {
                            console.log('data undefind: ', data)
                        }

                        // console.log(elem.messagesAdded[0].message)
                    } else {
                        console.log('elem.messages undefind: ', elem.messagesAdded)
                    }
                })
            )
            gmailAppDB.integrationData.historyId = response.data.historyId
            currUser.appIntegrations[currUser.appIntegrations.indexOf(gmailAppDB)] = gmailAppDB

            await currUser.save()
        } else {
            console.log('latest msg not found ', response.data.history[0])
        }
    }
     if (response.data.history) {
       fetchData().then(() => {
             console.log(addedMsgList)
        })
     } else {
         console.log('no new email >> ', response.data)
     }
    res.json({ res: response })
})
```